# rearranging exponential equation for Annualized Return

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I searched the site for an answer and had no joy.  Maybe I am using the wrong search terms.

Need help rearranging the equation for Annualized Return;  The equation is:

princial = Invested Amount  ($10,000)

Gain = is new value - princpal ($4,000)

days = number of days invested (913 days or 2.5 years)

365 is the number of days in a year

APY = ((principal + gain) / principal) ^ (365/days) - 1

APY = ((10000 + 4000) / 10000) ^ (365/913) - 1

APY 14%

Simple, no Issues there.

I need help rearranging the equation to solve for "gain"

14% = ((10000 + ***gain***) / 10000)^ (365/913) - 1

***gain*** = ????????????????

Can anyone help?  Thanks

Comment: Try formatting your equations with MathJax - also, can you show some progress that you have made on this question, or give some more context?

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the form
$$
a = \left( \frac{b + x}{c}\right)^d + e
$$
that you want to solve for $x$.

Subtract $e$ from both sides. Then raise each side to the power $1/d$.  You will be left with a linear equation for $x$ that's easy to solve.

This is more than "rearranging". Finding the $d$th root is a necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

The equation I am working with is:
$$  APY = \left( \frac{P + G}{P}\right) ^D - 1     $$
Where:

P = Principal = $10,000

G = Gain = $4,000

D = 365(Days in Year) / 913 (days Held) = 0.39978

$$  APY = \left( \frac{14000}{10000}\right) ^{0.39978} - 1      $$
$$  APY = {1.4} ^{0.39978} - 1      $$
$$  APY = 0.14398203      $$
$$  APY = 14.39\% $$

Now to Solve for G using 14.39% for the APY
$$  0.1439 = \left( \frac{10000 + G}{10000}\right) ^{0.39978} - 1     $$
Add 1 to both sides
$$  1.1439 = \left( \frac{10000 + G}{10000}\right) ^{0.39978}      $$
Cancel 10000
$$  1.1439 = {G} ^{0.39978}      $$
$$  1.1436 ^  \left( \frac{1}{0.39978}\right)  = G   $$
$$  G = 1.40000$$

Which is ***NOT*** correct.  It should be 4,000 give or take from rounding errors.
Any help on where I jumped the tracks??  Probably something incredibly foolish.

Calder, thanks for the MathJax response in the Original Post.  Never knew that existed.

Comment: This is not an answer - you should have edited into the question. Here is your error. You can't "cancel $10000$" that way. You seem to think $(a+b)/a = b$. That's not how fractions work! By the way, the APY rounds to $14.40$, not $14.39$.